# Vimscript: use vim settings as variables / How to check if specific guioption is set or not

Tags: vim

I want to make a toggle function in gvim that would turn on/off scrollbar and wrap option.

There is no problem for toggling wrap option. I simply use `set wrap!`.
To change horizontal scrollbar setting I need to check the value of `wrap` option or `guioptions`.

The question is how to read value of `wrap` or `guioptions`? Do you have some other hits?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title of your question because it appears that what you wanted was accessing settings as if they are variables.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `&setting` to access the value of a vim setting. See `:help expr-option`.

Here you can thus do:

```
if &guioptions =~# 'a'
   ....
endif
```

`=~#` in vimscript does case-sensitive regex matching.

Similarly, if you wanted to check if an option is *not* set,

```
if &guioptions !~# 'a'
   ....
endif
```

If you want to temporary save a setting:

```
let oldwrap=&wrap
set nowrap
... (your script assuming nowrap)
let &wrap=oldwrap
unlet oldwrap
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `.*`'s above. Just `&guioptions =~# 'a'` by itself will match any guioptions with an 'a' in it.