# how to check &somesettingname return a true value or boolean in vim script?

Tags: vim

I get how to check a setting exists in vimrc or not here [Vimscript: use vim settings as variables / How to check if specific guioption is set or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296659/vimscript-use-vim-settings-as-variables-how-to-check-if-specific-guioption-is?answertab=active#tab-top)

But I also get a question: if I set something like `tabstop=1` in vimrc,then `&tabstop` will return 1. If I have `set number` in vimrc,`&number` also return 1.So,how could I know wethear it returns a value of number or just a boolen in vim scripts?

Here is the why I am asking this question:I am writing a vimscript to add modeline to file base on vimrc.I let `modeline="modeoption=&modeoptions"`,and when I put expandtab into modeoptions I got things like `/*vim:expandtab=1:shiftwidth=4:tabstop=4:smarttab=1:*/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observation is right: Both boolean (`number` / `nonumber`) and integer options (e.g. `tabstop`) yield a number with the `&optionname` syntax. Vimscript doesn't have a dedicated Boolean type; true / false is represented by not 0 / 0.

Therefore, you have to hard-code the kind of option in your plugin in order to insert the correct format into a modeline. You can retrieve all options from `:help options.txt`.